# Can I install a mechanical timer switch on a stove circuit?

Tags: 240v, stove, timer

I’m looking to put a timer switch on a stove circuit. It’s a common area stove that a client doesn’t want used at night due to people turning it on and leaving it open. Is it possible to put a timer switch on a stove? It’s a 50 amp stove and plug on a 30 amp breaker. Wire size 10/3. What requirements would the timer switch need? Thank you!

Comment: A 50 amp stove should be on a 50 amp breaker and 6/3 wire.  A timer will need to handle 50 amps, good luck finding one cheap.  Certain words in your question might lead someone think this is not a one family home owned/not rented by the homeowner, so a licensed electrician is probably required also.

Comment: for a "client" no you can't not unless you're an electrician.

Comment: What's the deal with the 50A receptacle on the 30A breaker? Is this a dual fuel range, or an all-electric one, and what's its kW rating?

Comment: Are people turning it on and leaving it because otherwise it's unbearably cold in the house? If yes, it is possible what owner is doing is illegal, and you removing heat they need would also commit illegal act. Depends, of course, on jurisdiction. Some countries treat right to not freeze more seriously, than others. Also, 50 amp appliance on 30 amp breaker sounds like a hazard, or something you should explain better. If it's not tripping that breaker then something is wrong, either with the circuit or the way you described it.

Comment: @crip659 Unless I found the wrong product, a 50 amp timer is just $100; aka, within the realm of "cheap". https://www.amazon.com/Programmable-Timer-Control-Switch-9344204/dp/B01GXYGYYC. As for the rest of your comment, spot on!

Comment: @MonkeyZeus  Thought they would be more at that size.  That one might not be usable in North America, seeing it seems to only have a  CE listing.

Comment: @crip659 Good catch. They could get a [40 amp unit](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Intermatic-T1400-Series-40-Amp-24-Hour-Mechanical-Time-Switch-with-Skipper-and-Outdoor-Enclosure-Gray-T1471BR/205878313) for about $200; albeit I can't find whether it's UL listed. I assume it is since it's sold on Home Depot's site? [60 amp for $300](https://www.inyopools.com/Products/02400001004796.htm). Albeit not "cheap" anymore but still considerably cheaper than burning down a house of occupants.

Comment: @Molot: (a) stoves with multiple burners routinely use less than peak power.  (b) note "common area" --- if it's being used for heat, it's probably not because the individual units don't have heating capacity, but because running the heat inside a unit gets billed to the unit's individual electric account, while the landlord is footing the bill for common areas.

Answer (score 8):

50-Amp contactors are available. These are essentially relays. A standard timer can run the coil of the contactor, then the contactor can switch the stove circuit off at the desired times. Web-search "50 Amp contactor".

Please note per Crip659's comments, that if this is a rental unit or group home that your client wants you to modify this circuit, law may require you to use a licensed electrician and get inspections.

Comment: Make sure that you switch both hots. A stove uses both hots and neutral so switching just one hot could leave it half working and very confusing.

Comment: Would this come under having to use a licensed electrician if this is a group home/non owned(rental) homeowner type housing?  The words client/common area seems to indicate not a homeowner type house.

Answer (score 4):

Your options for installing ready-made solutions or assembling your own depend on a few things.

Firstly, if you are *not* the homeowner, you are limited *plug-in* timer or safety/shut-off products. If you can buy it ready to plug in, and it has the proper certification e.g. UL, cUL etc...) for where you live, you can install it and use it yourself.

Here are two examples:

[image]

Image: https://www.cnet.com/reviews/wallflower-review/

The depicted one will send alerts over wifi, but it does not have a shut-off relay. This may not be what you asked for, but it is plug-in and it can still somewhat help by alerting persons in charge.

An alternative which is also a plug-in, shown below, does have a cut off switch. It works off a cooking time limit and includes motion detection. Upon a cursory review of the specs I didn't see lock-out time periods, so it appears that its much higher cost won't help you with your objective.

[image]

The above options are UL approved as plug-ins and you do not need a permit or inspection to installs them.

However, if you *are* the home owner and plan to build an enclosure with a timer and a "contactor" (a 50A relay), you must pay special attention to the wiring and connections, and have your work checked by an electrician or experienced electrical DIY.

Wiring mistakes, incl. minor flaws in high current circuits and screw terminals, can heat up quickly to become a fire hazard.

There are different approval rules for assembling low/high power equipment, low/high voltage equipment, and for assembling equipment composed of listed (UL) parts, even if you are using it yourself and not selling it.

Furthermore, your jurisdiction may require a permit, and your insurance may require an inspection. If you want to go down this path, you can post different questions here on this forum  or on https://electronics.stackexchange.com

The 50A / 30A is already a red flag: this is not legal and it's bad practice. However, although the wiring is not adequate, the breaker is protecting the wire.

Comment: The Wallflower link leads to another stove plug device that does kill stove power.

Comment: @Triplefault you convinced me to include it. I saw it in a different review and left it out, but I suppose it's indeed still worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, yes, you can.

Long answer. First of all, check local rules. As example, my friends in Norway owns their house. During covid and spending a lot o time at home, they installed wall socket. After a while, had inspection, that forced them to pay certified electrician to remove it (with cables), and install new one. In total several thousands euros (and about half of it for removing). Also goverment inspector was very generous and not issued fine for a first time braking a law.

Second. Looks like you are don't have professional education or something like that. 30A is very dangerous if wired improperly. It may cause fire, injure or even death. Moreover, cheap and/or simple electrical connections (like simple screw) need to be checked on regular basis, like 1 time/per X years (depends on connection time, overloads, indoor/outdoor, constant/temporary living indoor etc). More reliable connections includes screw and spring, so when screw will loosen a bit over years, spring will maintain good connection.

Third. Both ideas mentioned by collegues don't keep in mind human factor. Like, personal want to heat up room and you will add timer, accesabble by them, what will prevent them to move timer to other sockey (maybe with adapter), insert stove into wall socket and turn it on? If personal have poor education, what will prevent them to buy adapter (or hand made it), than insert stove into regular socket, and than repeatedly turn on automatic circuit braker if there is one, causing risk of fire with all that actions?

IMHO, probably it's much cheaper and less risky to just buy several oil heaters for staff? Or invest into aircon with heating functions and ability to work in winter?

Forth. The working solution should be: metal safety box with locker,  automatic timer inside (timer solution mentioned in other posts already), proper exit/entrance of power in box, safety temperature control in box, liquid resistance for cases of human mistakes in kitchen. All of it is not cheap, neither easy to install solution. But this is only safety prooved aproach I could imagine.